# ERROR command failed: npm install --loglevel error @vue/cli-plugin-babel@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-service@~4.5.0 --save-dev

Tags: npm-scripts

ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error @vue/cli-plugin-babel@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-service@~4.5.0 --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error @vue/cli-plugin-babel@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@~4.5.0 @vue/cli-service@~4.5.0 --save-dev

Comment: This is not an answer and is a duplicate of the error in the question. Should be deleted.